# Tangent plane to a surface problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem:
Show that the tangent plane to the surface $xyz = a^3$ at the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is
$$
\frac{x}{x_0} + \frac{y}{y_0} + \frac{z}{z_0} = 3
$$

When I solve it I get:
$$
\frac{x_0}{x} + \frac{y_0}{y} + \frac{z_0}{z} = 3
$$
Is my answer incorrect and if it is, then how do I solve it?

Comment: The equation of a plane is generally $Ax+By+Cz=D$, not $A/x+B/y+C/z=D$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x,y,z)=xyz-a^3$.Then we can have $$F_x=yz,F_y=xz,F_z=xy.$$
so the normal vector at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is $(y_0z_0,x_0z_0,y_0z_0)=a^3(\dfrac{1}{x_0},\dfrac{1}{y_0},\dfrac{1}{z_0})$.

The tangent plane is $F_x(x-x_0)+F_y(y-y_0)+F_z(z-z_0)=0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{x}{x_0}+\dfrac{y}{y_0}+\dfrac{z}{z_0}=3$.

Comment: I see, my mistake was to write z = f(x, y)